# Apache API: `ap_parse_form_data` getting the data? example?

Tags: c, forms, apache, http, post

I am trying to use `ap_parse_form_data` to parse a POST request:

```
request_rec* R = ...;
apr_array_header_t* H;
ap_parse_form_data(R, NULL, &H, -1, 1 << 20);
```

I would like to have two operations on `H`:

Get an entry by the key of `"foo"`:

```
const char* val = ap_get_header(H, "foo");
```

And walking all key/values:

```
while (ap_has_more_headers(H))
{
    const char* key = ap_get_next_header_key(H);
    const char* value = ap_get_next_header_value(H);
    ...
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this or where it is documented?  (`ap_get_header`, `ap_has_more_headers`, `ap_get_next_header_key` and `ap_get_next_header_value` are imaginary API calls to show what I want to do.)

Also do I need to release `H` somehow?

A working example of using `ap_parse_form_data` in these two use cases would be great.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html#snippets

Comment: @mebjas - thanks! that's helped me a lot. Please note you shouldn't run ap_parse_form_data before readPost(..). Hope it will help someone someday

Comment: @ItayB this was the bug I searched today for hours. Thanks!